# What does RoutedEventHandler do?

Tags: wpf, resharper

Do I need it?  I've always used it, but recently noticed ReSharper saying to get rid of it.  For example:

```
feedbackButton.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(OnFeedbackClick);
```

appears to reduce to

```
feedbackButton.Click += OnFeedbackClick;
```

with no issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of these code snippet exactly do the same job or in fact they are both same.

In the first example you are explicitly providing a type of the delegate which is a must if you are using 1.1 or 2.0 framework version.

But in the second example you let your compiler  find the appropriate delegate type at the **compile time** which is known as [type inferencing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx#csharp3.0overview_topic10) and that works only from 3.0 framework version.

Answer (score 0):

In C# 1.0 it was mandatory to specify delegates type explicitly. In later versions it become optional, since compiler got type inference for delegates.